# ansible: put stdout to dictionary

Tags: ansible

I'm parsing the zabix configuration file to get the variables, this can be done in separate tasks, but I want to do it in one. I need to put the output of a command into a dictionary. How to register this vars from file?

ROLE

```
# tasks file for roles/test
- name: Read vars
  shell: egrep -v -e "^#|^$" /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
  register: zbaconfig

- name: Debug 1
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ zbaconfig.stdout_lines }}"

- name: Register vars
  set_fact:
    zba: "{{ dict(zbaconfig.stdout | split('\\n') | select() | map('split','=') | list) }}"

- name: Debug 2
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ zba.Hostname }}"
      - "{{ zba.ServerActive }}"
      - "{{ zba.Server }}"
```

STDOUT

```
TASK [test : Debug 1] 
ok: [10.100.0.52] => {
        "msg": [
        [
            "PidFile=/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid",
            "LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log",
            "LogFileSize=0",
            "Server=zabbix.domain.com.ua",
            "ServerActive=zabbix.domain.com.ua",
            "Hostname=vs-net-dk01",
            "Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/*.conf"
        ],

TASK [test : Register vars] 
fatal: [10.100.0.52]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'split'. String: {{ dict(zbaconfig.stdout | split('\n') | select() | map('split','=') | list) }}"}
```

Comment: The irony of you asking about `| split` right underneath the debug where you knew about `.stdout_lines` is some :chefs_kiss: but anyway, watch out for that `map("split"` since as written it will do bad things to `"Alpha=Beta=Charlie"`, what you likely want is `map("split", "=", 1)` to tell it you only want it to split on the first `=` not _all_ of them

Comment: dont forget to close your post by validating the answer you prefer..

Answer (score 1):

following the version of ansible you have, the plugin `split` doesnt exist, but you could use the python version like this:

```
- name: Register vars
  set_fact:
    zba: "{{ dict( (zbaconfig.stdout.split('\\n')) | select() | map('split','=') | list) }}"
```

but its better to work directly with stdout_lines

Comment: I had never noticed they had made this an actual filter.... Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thank's for help. I got ansible version issue again. Split is not available in versions below 2.11. Here is the option that works for me. zba: "{{ dict((zbaconfig.stdout_lines) | select() | map('split','=') | list) }}"

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter [*community.general.jc*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/cli_parsing.html#parsing-with-jc)

```yaml
  zba: "{{ zbaconfig.stdout|community.general.jc('ini') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  zba:
    Hostname: vs-net-dk01
    Include: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/*.con
    LogFile: /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
    LogFileSize: '0'
    PidFile: /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
    Server: zabbix.domain.com.ua
    ServerActive: zabbix.domain.com.ua
```

---

**Notes**

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    zbaconfig:
      stdout: |
        PidFile=/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
        LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
        LogFileSize=0
        Server=zabbix.domain.com.ua
        ServerActive=zabbix.domain.com.ua
        Hostname=vs-net-dk01
        Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/*.con

    zba: "{{ zbaconfig.stdout|community.general.jc('ini') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: zba
```

- Install the latest [jc](https://pypi.org/project/jc/)

```bash
   shell> pip3 install -U jc
```

- Test it

```bash
   shell> cat test.ini
   PidFile=/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
```

```bash
   shell> cat test.ini | jc --ini
   {"PidFile":"/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid"}
```